# ionic app cannot fully scroll down when ion-scroll height is too high

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I encountered this strange problem with an ionic app. The ionic app cannot fully scroll down. For example, I may have a table with 100 rows. I can at most scroll down to the 80th row. Here is the relevant html code.

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="height:700px">
      <table ng-table="tableParams" style="width:600px">
        <!-- table contents -->
      </table>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

I later discovered the solution but I do not know why it works. The solution is to lower the height from 700px to 500px. `<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="height:500px">`

I have no idea why it works. Can someone explain?

EDIT: One of the answers mentioned that the problem was that height was specified in absolute terms. How can I specify the height such that it can work on mobile devices of different heights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using absolute pixel heights for your containers.  If the device is not at least 700 pixels high you will cut off the bottom of the scroll container.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. is there a better way to specify the height? How can I specify the height such that it can work on mobile devices of different heights?

Comment: Does it need to be full height?

Comment: no need. As long as I can scroll to the last row of the table.

Comment: You can do CSS media queries on browser height - 

@media (min-height:700px) {
   // code here
}

Answer (score 2):

remove the inline style height for that container cause below 700px it will not visible view your webpage  on screen

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:  height: 33vh;